# GitHub CI/CD - Run elevated commands

Tags: github, installation, github-actions

I have a CI/CD pipeline in GitHub.

I need to run a software in elevated permission (e.g "Run As Administrator") in the pipeline

Currently running:

step:

run: software.exe

gives error:`light.exe : error LGHT0217`.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the issue:

GitHub pipeline runs as **administrator**.

To solve the `light.exe : error LGHT0217`
I added

```
 project.LightOptions = "-sval";
```